# Getting a dictionnary of lists that contain element from a column using a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this, with 1 string column and 1 int column.

```
import random
columns=['EG','EC','FI', 'ED', 'EB', 'FB', 'FCY', 'ECY', 'FG', 'FUR', 'E', '\[ED']
choices_str = random.choices(columns, k=200)
choices_int = random.choices(range(1, 8), k=200)
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'column_A': choices_str, 'column_B': choices_int})
```

[image]

I would like to get at the very end a dictionnary of lists that store all values of column B groupby A, like this :

[image]

What I made to achieve this to used a groupby to get number of occurences for column_B :

```
group_by = my_df.groupby(['column_A','column_B'])['column_B'].count().unstack().fillna(0).T
group_by
```

[image]

And then use some list comprehensions to create by hand my lists for each column_A and add them to the dictionnary.
Is there anyway to get more directly using a groupby ?

Comment: please provide a **minimal reproducible** example, as DataFrame constructors/dictionary (**text**!)

Comment: I put a sample of the dataframe

Comment: `my_df.groupby('column_A')['column_B'].agg(list).to_dict()`?

Comment: @mozway, if that works it would probably be the smoothest way to achieve that

Comment: @ko3 give it a try ;)

Comment: @mozway this is indeed what i was looking for ! Very smooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a method that is able to achieve that within the `groupby` statement. But I think you could try something like this alternatively:

```py
import random
import pandas as pd
columns=['EG','EC','FI', 'ED', 'EB', 'FB', 'FCY', 'ECY', 'FG', 'FUR', 'E', '\[ED']
choices_str = random.choices(columns, k=200)
choices_int = random.choices(range(1, 8), k=200)
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'column_A': choices_str, 'column_B': choices_int})

final_dict = {val: my_df.loc[my_df['column_A'] == val, 'column_B'].values.tolist() for val in my_df['column_A'].unique()}
```

This dict-comprehension is a one-liner and takes all `column_B` values that correspond to a specific `column_A` value and assigns them to the dict stored in a list with `column_A` values as keys.